# Why is Ubuntu Dockerfile not building with WSL2 backend, but building with Hyper-V backend when using Docker Desktop on Windows 11

Tags: docker, hyper-v, wsl-2, docker-desktop

I'm trying to build a Dockerfile with Docker Desktop on Win 11 that builds perfectly fine on Ubuntu 22.04.

This is the first few lines of the Dockerfile. It hangs at the `apt update` part on Windows.

```
FROM osrf/ros:kinetic-desktop-full as base
# https://hub.docker.com/r/osrf/ros
# If you're using one of the third party scripts you must have a base layer.

# nvidia-container-runtime
ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES \
    ${NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES:-all}
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES \
    ${NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES:+$NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES,}graphics

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl
```

This is the output I get, the Get/Ign is repeated as it seems indefinitely. What is also strange to me, that the step it hangs on should be the 4th step, not the 2nd (on Ubuntu it *is* the 4th step).

```
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                             0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2.89kB                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/osrf/ros:kinetic-desktop-full                         1.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2.77MB                                                              0.1s
 => CACHED [ 1/18] FROM docker.io/osrf/ros:kinetic-desktop-full@sha256:e350d250d704f10ae43039e7  0.0s
 => [ 2/18] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl                       67.5s
 => => # Ign:1 http://snapshots.ros.org/kinetic/final/ubuntu xenial InRelease
 => => # Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
 => => # Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
 => => # Get:4 http://snapshots.ros.org/kinetic/final/ubuntu xenial Release [13.1 kB]
 => => # Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [99.8 kB]
 => => # Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release [98.8 kB]
```

Any ideas what might be going wrong here?

Comment: It seems like something network problems. Cause there are 18 packages to get but now it's only processing the 6th one.

Comment: Hmm, 6 and 2 are the same, but there's no network error shown and we've checked it on different windows boxes as well.

Comment: I did some testing and it seems that when using the WSL 2 backend it doesn't work, but works when using the Hyper-V backend.